# How to traverse data according to an array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to traverse the data according to the `show` array and print the data to see if it is correct. To traverse the `list` array corresponding to the `show` array as follows

**I want the effect as follows:**

```
[
  {
   "name": "A",
   "age": "10",
  },
  {
   "name": "B",
   "age": "20",
  }
]
```

```js
const data = [{
  "code": "200",
  "msg": "success",
  "data": {
    "list": [{
      "name": "A",
      "age": "10",
      "logo": "aa.png",
      "note": "aa"
    }, {
      "name": "B",
      "age": "20",
      "logo": "bb.png",
      "note": "bb"
    }],
    "show": [
      "name",
      "age"
    ]
  }
}]



function init() {
  data.map(res => {
    if (res.code == 200) {
      console.log(res.data.list)
    }

  })
}
init();
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: `for(var i=0;i<res.data.list.length;i++) { console.log(res.data.list[i]); }` Use the for to loop through your js array object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By iterating `show` (rather than hard-coding `name` and `age`), this code would work also if you change the structure of your template:

```js
const data = [{
  "code": "200",
  "msg": "success",
  "data": {
    "list": [{
      "name": "A",
      "age": "10",
      "logo": "aa.png",
      "note": "aa"
    }, {
      "name": "B",
      "age": "20",
      "logo": "bb.png",
      "note": "bb"
    }],
    "show": [
      "name",
      "age"
    ]
  }
}];

var ans = data[0].data.list.map(item => {
  var curr = {};
  data[0].data.show.forEach(prop => {
    curr[prop] = item[prop];
  });
  return curr;
});

console.log(ans);
```

Comment: Also note that this solution assumes one element in the `data` array. If there are no elements this results in an error. If there are multiple elements only the first is used.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Thanks, I've turned the `map` into `forEach` in the nested loop

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` in a shorter way:

```js
const data = [
  {
    code: "200",
    msg: "success",
    data: {
      list: [
        {
          name: "A",
          age: "10",
          logo: "aa.png",
          note: "aa"
        },
        {
          name: "B",
          age: "20",
          logo: "bb.png",
          note: "bb"
        }
      ],
      show: ["name", "age"]
    }
  }
];

console.log(data[0].data.list.map(x =>
  data[0].data.show.reduce((p, c) => ((p[c] = x[c]), p), {})
));
```

Comment: Gotta love 'reduce'!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [{
  "code": "200",
  "msg": "success",
  "data": {
    "list": [{
      "name": "A",
      "age": "10",
      "logo": "aa.png",
      "note": "aa"
    }, {
      "name": "B",
      "age": "20",
      "logo": "bb.png",
      "note": "bb"
    }],
    "show": [
      "name",
      "age"
    ]
  }
}];

function init() {
  data.map(res => {
    if (res.code == 200) {
      console.log(res.data.list.map(function(listValue) {
        var ret = {};
        res.data.show.forEach(function(idx) {
          ret[idx] = listValue[idx]
        });
        return ret;
      }));
    }

  })
}
init();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map` on your `data` and return `false` if the code isn't 200, if it is 200, you can return a mapped version of your `list` array. You can map this array to a subset of each object in your list. The subset is defined by your `show` array, and so you can use `.reduce()` on this array to build your mapped object.

See example below:

```js
const data = [{
  "code": "200",
  "msg": "success",
  "data": {
    "list": [{
      "name": "A",
      "age": "10",
      "logo": "aa.png",
      "note": "aa"
    }, {
      "name": "B",
      "age": "20",
      "logo": "bb.png",
      "note": "bb"
    }],
    "show": [
      "name",
      "age"
    ]
  }
}];



function init() {
  return data.map(res => {
    if (res.code == 200) {
      return res.data.list.map((obj) => {
       return res.data.show.reduce((acc, prop) => ({...acc, [prop]: obj[prop]}), {});
      });
    }
    return false;
  }).filter(Boolean); // filter out any `false` returns
}

console.log(init());
```

Alternatively, a better approach than mapping your original data would be to use `.reduce()`. This will create a one-dimensional array of results:

```js
const data = [{
  "code": "200",
  "msg": "success",
  "data": {
    "list": [{
      "name": "A",
      "age": "10",
      "logo": "aa.png",
      "note": "aa"
    }, {
      "name": "B",
      "age": "20",
      "logo": "bb.png",
      "note": "bb"
    }],
    "show": [
      "name",
      "age"
    ]
  }
},
{
  "code": "200",
  "msg": "success",
  "data": {
    "list": [{
      "name": "C",
      "age": "30",
      "logo": "aa.png",
      "note": "aa"
    }, {
      "name": "D",
      "age": "40",
      "logo": "bb.png",
      "note": "bb"
    }],
    "show": [
      "name",
      "age"
    ]
  }
}];



function init() {
  return data.reduce((acc, res) => {
    if (res.code == 200) {
      return [...acc, ...res.data.list.map((obj) => {
       return res.data.show.reduce((acc, prop) => ({...acc, [prop]: obj[prop]}), {});
      })];
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(init());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only name and age as

```
[
{
   "name": "A",
   "age": "10",
},
{
   "name": "B",
   "age": "20",
}
]
```

`Array.map` can be used

and then you can write your code this way

```js
const data = [
    {
        code: '200',
        msg: 'success',
        data: {
            list: [
                {
                    name: 'A',
                    age: '10',
                    logo: 'aa.png',
                    note: 'aa'
                },
                {
                    name: 'B',
                    age: '20',
                    logo: 'bb.png',
                    note: 'bb'
                }
            ],
            show: ['name', 'age']
        }
    }
]

function init() {
    data.map(res => {
        if (res.code == 200) {
            console.log(
                res.data.list.map(item => {
                    return {
                        name: item.name,
                        age: item.age
                    }
                })
            )
        }
    })
}
init()
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: The print result is correct, but can you print the results according to show: ['name', 'age']？

Comment: If  `"show": [ "name","age","logo" ]` then your solution will not work.